# C++ Benchmark Code Crashing - long numbers

Tags: c++

Beginner here...

Doing a code to check language performance in Cpp, Java and Python.

The code must generate a random number N (1-60), fill a NxN matrix with random numbers between 0 and 9 and calculate its determinant.

I started with cpp, but sometimes it succeeds, sometimes it fails. My guess is that crashes are related to bigger than "long long int" numbers. Can you guys please check my code?

GNU GCC / CodeBlocks.

Thanks,

Guile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

struct Mat{
int N = 2;
int mat[60][60];
long long int det;
};

void setSize(Mat *Size){
    srand (time(NULL));
    do {
         Size->N = rand()%60;
    }
    while (Size->N < 1);
}

void setMatrix (Mat *mat){
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < mat->N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < mat->N; j++){
            mat->mat[i][j] = rand()%10;
        }
    }
}

void det(Mat *m1){
    int i, j, k;
    long long int Ratio;
    long long int determinant;
    for(i = 0; i < m1->N; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m1->N; j++){
            if(j>i){
                Ratio = m1->mat[j][i]/m1->mat[i][i];
                for(k = 0; k < m1->N; k++){
                m1->mat[j][k] -= Ratio * m1->mat[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    determinant = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < m1->N; i++)
    determinant *= m1->mat[i][i];
    m1->det = determinant;
}

int main (void){

Mat M1;
setSize(&M1);
setMatrix (&M1);
det(&M1);

cout<<"Matrix size: "<<M1.N<<endl;
cout<<"Matrix determinant: "<<M1.det<<"\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged with C++. But it is pure C-Code. The ````std::cout```` will not change my opinion. So, If you want to benchmark C++ Code, then write C++ code. Everything else is comparing apples to pies. . . .

Comment: @OP Also, you do know that C++ has a much better random number generator, better than `rand()`?  And not only that, you don't need to do that `%` to get a uniformly distributed random number.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you tell me more about it/terms I can look it up with?

Comment: @a.Li [See this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: Why are you guessing what the reason for the crash is? Did you know that your debugger will happily tell you exactly what the reason is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your function `setMatrix`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < mat->N; j++){
    mat->mat[i][j] = rand()%10;
}
```

`rand() % 10` can sometimes generate 0 as well, thus putting zeroes inside your matrix. This will cause a floating-point exception when you do:

```
Ratio = m1->mat[j][i]/m1->mat[i][i];
```

This line will again cause an issue when you do

```
m1->mat[j][k] -= Ratio * m1->mat[i][k];
```

which can again set a zero in your matrix at `mat[j][k]` later which can become the denominator again, causing the floating-point exception.

Comment: Thank you Jarvis!